# OOP Design issues

Tags: java, oop

I think it's a minor problem, maybe even subjective, but it really bothers me. Whenever I create something (games, mostly) composed of a grid of cells. I tend to have the same getters for the cells, and for the grid. To explain clearly, here are code examples:

```
class Cell{
    private int value1;
    private boolean value2;

    public Cell(int value1, boolean value2){
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    public int getValue1(){
        return value1;
    }

    public boolean getValue2{
        return value2;
    }
}
```

And here's my grid class:

```
class Grid{
    private Cell[][] cells;

    public Grid(int rows, int cols){
        cells = new Cell[rows][cols];
        // initialize
    }

    public int getCellValue1(int row, int col){
        return cells[row][col].getValue1();
    }

    public boolean getCellValue2(int row, int col){
        return cells[row][col].getValue2();
    }

    // setters, same idea
}
```

I don't know. I may be over-thinking things, and this might be a dumb question, but, is there a better way to do it? Maybe it's just me, but I feel like it's a bit clunky, and a lot of extra code. Is this design fine?

Comment: `value2` is a `boolean` (not an `int`); `public Cell(int value1, boolean value2){`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would change Edwin's `Grid` class to an interface like this:

```
public interface Grid {
    public void setValue(String value, int row, int column);
    public String getValue(int row, int column);
}
```

The `CellGrid` class implements a `Grid` using a two-dimensional array of `Cell`s:

```
class CellGrid implements Grid {
    private Cell[][] cells;

    public CellGrid(int rows, int cols){
        cells = new Cell[rows][cols];
        // initialize
    }

    // get a value using the implementation we chose
    public String getValue(int row, int col) {
        return cells[row][col].getValue();
    }
}
```

Your `Cell` class remains largely unchanged, except that I changed the type of `value1` from `int` to `String`:

```
class Cell {
    private String value;
    // other fields can go here

    public Cell(String value, ...){
        this.value = value;
        // ...
    }

    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

You can access a particular property of a cell with the following code:

`grid.getValue(2, 2)`

Not that when you make this call, you do not need to know anything about the implementation of the `Grid`.  As I mentioned in my original answer, the `CellGrid` class does not have any dependency on the inner working of its `Cell`s.

Comment: I like your idea and I am convinced. I just want to be clear. You said avoid making the Grid class dependent on Cell. To me, @Edwin Buck seem to say the opposite.  That the Grid class should abstract the workings of Cell.

Comment: The `Grid` class should then either be an `abstract` class or an `interface`, and in my updated response I chose the latter.

Comment: So, is the `public String getValue()` design better than the `public Cell getCell()` one?

Comment: If you go with `public Cell getCell()` then you would be mixing implementation details with your interface (which is bad design).  We could generalize to `public Object getObject()` instead of using a `String`.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is a data structure in a class construct.

You can't have a "OO"-Class without some behavior.

The grid example at least has a tiny amount of behavior, as you can decouple the finding of an element with where it is stored.  For example, in Tim's `Grid` eample, I could change the storage layout to be implemented with a HashMap, where the row and column value were inputs into a hash function, and the same hash function was used to retrieve the same element.

In such a case, the Grid would have the "behavior" of storing and retrieving Cells; however that's still giving away too much of the data structure.  In my Grid, I would just take and give back the data

```
public class Grid {
  public void setValue(String value, int row, int column) {
    ...
  }

  public String getValue(int row, int column) {
    ...
  }
}
```

The key is that in my "improved" example, even more details of the implementation are hidden from the "user" (a programmer) of the class.  Appropriate data hiding is essential to good Object-Oriented programming; because, it permits the person using the class to start seeing it as a "black box" where the need to know how it is implemented is not important in understanding how to use it.

When you can use something without the need to know exactly how it works, you have a highly usable component.  That's good (low level) design.

Good design makes life easier.  For example, your toaster probably has a "start" button, a "browning adjustment" knob, and a power indicator light.  It really doesn't need very much more, and if you had to know how those components were connected internally, the swapping toasters would be a much more difficult task as you had to relearn how your "new toaster" was built.

Comment: Voted up for first two sentences.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is good design. For the foundation class likes cells in the project, you have to define the basic properties(variables) and implement the functions. I would not bother the constructors, getters and setters since IDE like eclipse can help automatically generate these. Right click-> source -> generate getters and setters. (Think about why IDE provide these)

While in the grid class, my habit is that I usually don't write the getters and setters since typing the function name and parameters required may not save your time compared with directly using the array[][] to fetch the value, except that you want to add more operations in the simple getters and setters.

No matter what, it is a good OOP design. Tedious but clear and highly readable.